# Преобразование строки в дату нужного формата

Tags: java

22 окт 18, 16:03   -  приходит такая строка, можно как-то её сохранять и на выходе получать 29-10-2018 16:05 для TimeStamp  sql?
у меня объект в java принимает строку 22 окт 18, 16:03
можно как-то  сделать чтобы он принимая подобную строку хранил строку формата
29-10-2018 16:05  и  возвращал строку такого же формата?    есть же стандартные решения какой класс лучше использовать кто с таким сталкивался?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/781354/263913 возможно вот решение вашей проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Timestamp ts = new Timestamp` ((твоя дата, в формате `Date.getDate()`)

`ts.toString();`

Comment: приведите пример устал эксперементировать

Comment: DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MM yy, hh:mm");  date = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);  и вот прилетает строка 25 02 18, 11:14

Comment: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '25 02 18, 11:14' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=14, HourOfAmPm=11}

Comment: ,ISO resolved to 2018-02-25 of type java.time.format.Parsed
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '25 02 18, 11:14' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=14, HourOfAmPm=11},ISO resolved to 2018-02-25 of type java.time.format.Parsed

Comment: во-первых откуда приходит строка?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm");   Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);

Comment: https://rsdn.org/forum/java/4389143.hot тут вот хак для вашего случая